# How to make parallel curves in photoshop CS6?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers, cs6, shapes

I want to replicate this picture, but I'm having a hard time figuring out how can I make identical parallel curves. Can someone with better skills give me a little help?

[image]

I tried making curves with a pen tool, then making selections out of it and then layer by layer would try to replicate what's in the image, but that would't work for me, because the curves wouldn't be the same. Then I tried making a big ellipse selection to match curves in the image, but that's I think is too much work, there has to be an easier solution.

Comment: Why do you want to do this in Photoshop? It seems like a much better job for Illustrator on the face of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Get the Eclipse Tool (U).
2. Left click on the canvas and put 100px width & 100px height and then
   click ok.
3. Repeat the 2nd step but put 200px width & 200px height. Do this
   again but increase but 100px for the amount of circles you want. You will then have to move the layer order so the biggest circle is on the bottom.
4. Once you have 6 or so circles select one of the shape layers with the move tools (V). Press CTRL/CMD + A and at the top click on Align Vertical Centers & Align Horizontal Centers. Do this for all shape layers.

[image: align options]

5. Select all layers and enlarge with the the transform tool CTRL/CMD + T. Make sure to hold Shift when enlarging. At a certain point I squashed the circle and rotated the circles.

[image: rotated circles demo]

Result

[image: end result]

Comment: Great solution still having difficulties figuring out what size biggest circle to make to crop out 1440x2560.

Comment: @Giancarlo Make the document 1440x2560. My method starts with the circle size 100x by 100px but that doesn't really matter. What matters is how you scale the second circle. I am doing 2x which makes my second circle 200px by 200px. The end result has the circles much bigger than what they started out as.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a segment of concentric circles. To draw them perfectly lined up follow the steps below and afterwards crop the image to your liking. It will start as a large circle with smaller circles inside:

1. Decide on the largest circle size and get your canvas size, remember you will crop only a part of it so be generous
2. Pull one guide from the top ruler down roughly to the middle of the canvas, do the same from the left ruler. These will mark the center of the circles
3. Pick up the elliptical marquee tool, bring your cursor close to the intersection of the guides
4. Hold down the Alt and Shift keys and drag outward to draw the largest circle. Shift key constrains it to a circle, Alt key starts from the center out.
5. Fill this with a color you want
6. Add a blank layer above this if you want to be able to change the color of the circles
7. Repeat step #4 and draw a smaller circle, the example curves are not evenly spaced, you decide how you want to draw them. Fill this with the second color
8. Repeat steps #6 and #7 which includes step #4

Do this as many times as you like. Then pick up the crop tool and crop the section that resembles your sample.

**UPDATE**

I noticed that you are having difficulty deciding on the starting size of the circles. If you want to end up with 2500px tall image, start with a canvas and outer circle size of about 9000 pixels. Since the end result is solid colors, you can also resample up or down depending on the area you crop after the fact. You should not have any visible quality loss.

Comment: Thank you. I guess I was able to make something [similar](http://i.imgur.com/Xg41kjq.jpg), but I still need more practice with this. I'm not sure what size of document to make in the beginning, because I need the result picture to be 1440x2560, so I guess I have to figure that out.

Comment: @Giancarlo I'm admittedly biased because I use it more, but if you have it available then Illustrator might be a more comfortable tool to design this in. The concept of how to create this graphic would be the same as in PS. Ai has a more "fluid" concept of document size, and with vector you can always export at any size you want and not lose quality.

Answer (score 0):

You can get to the answer in Photoshop in various ways, just as other people mentioned here, all of them are good but THE BEST ONE is:

**Use Illustrator!**

It's much easier to create and control the shapes and colors in AI. Then, copy the final shapes to PS and place either as a Smart Object (editable via AI) or as shape layers (editable via PS)

Voila! :D